# How in magento add manufacturer in the URL of the product?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

How can I change magento so that:

```
{site}/category-name/sub-category/product-name
```

becomes

```
{site}/category-name/sub-category/manufacturer/product-name
```

Where is the standard Magento manufacturer attribute?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to overwrite the system's url rewrites to do that. You could either extend the class that creates the product rewrites in the first place (it probably happens somewhere in the product controller in the admin site) or create an event observer which updates the rewrites after the product is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create any necessary attributes for manufacturer, etc, in the admin panel if you want to use them, but that won't really solve this problem. I understand what you're looking to do, but messing with the parsing of product URLs doesn't seem like a great idea (you're likely to run into problems). You could probably change the product url in the database (usually saved as 'some-product-name.html') to something along the lines of 'manufacturer-name/some-product-name.html'. I don't see any immediate reason why that wouldn't work, though allowing the customer to change that themselves may not be trivial.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

It is a workaround, but you could create a manufacturer subcategory and place the products in there?

So:

`root -> subcategory -> manufacturer-subcategory -> product`

?

Because as per Joseph's answer, I think what you're attempting to do would be a little messy.